# Can't seem to get a recurrence relation when applying the Frobenius Method to the following ODE.

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, frobenius-method

$$x^2y'' -2xy' + 2y = 0 $$
Substituting in $ y = \sum_{i = 0}^\infty a_ix^i$ to obtain:
$$ \sum_{i = 2}^\infty i(i-1)a_ix^i -2\sum_{i = 1}^\infty ia_ix^i +2\sum_{i = 0}^\infty a_ix^i = 0. $$
Matching up indexes:
$$ \sum_{i = 2}^\infty i(i-1)a_ix^i -2a_1x -2\sum_{i = 2}^\infty ia_ix^i +2a_0 + 2a_1x + 2\sum_{i = 2}^\infty a_ix^i = 0. $$
How do I set up a recurrence relation with this?

Comment: This means that there is no restriction on $a_1$.

Comment: $x=0$ is a singular point so you will only get the trivial solution $y=0$ if you do it that way. Look at [this explanation](https://math.libretexts.org/Bookshelves/Differential_Equations/Book%3A_Differential_Equations_for_Engineers_(Lebl)/7%3A_Power_series_methods/7.3%3A_Singular_Points_and_the_Method_of_Frobenius).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you include terms that are automatically zero, you can start all sums at zero. You get
$$
\sum_{i=0}^\infty (i^2-3i+2)a_ix^i=0
$$
which gives exactly two coefficients that can be non-zero.

You are lucky that the indicial equation has integer solutions, otherwise there are no solutions that are simple power series.

Comment: Sorry, but which two coefficients?

Comment: Those where $i^2-3i+2=0$.